# How can I add new points to an existing path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've drawn a path with the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator. I did some other work, but now I want to **extend** the path with more points. How can I continue drawing the path where if I click off of the path, it generates a new anchor point and connects it?

I know I could keep adding more points along the existing path using the "add anchor point", but I'd like to keep drawing as if I had never stopped drawing the original path (click a new place on the screen, and the path continues to there).

Answer (score 13):

With the **Pen Tool** start by clicking the anchor point at the *end* of the existing path.... then you can continue drawing.

The pen tool icon will have a little **/** next to it indicate clicking will continue the existing path. If you aren't exactly over the path endpoint, you'll see a * instead, which indicates a new path.

[image: Continue Path] <-- Continue Path vs New Path --> [image: New Path]

[image: continue with precise] <--- if precise cursors are enabled

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to achieve that is using Blob Brush Tool:

[image]

[image]